# Getting a value from a single property of a single object in an array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with Node.js and MongoDB, I used this line:`db.collection('users').insertOne({"name":"john", "password":"connor"})` to insert a new document, and now I'd like to get the password from it.

I tried with: `var users_array = db.collection('users').find({name:"john"},{password:true, _id:false}).toArray()` and I get an array that looks like this: `[{"password":"connor"}]`

Any way to get that value and save it in a string or something similar?

Comment: `var pwString = yourArray[0].password`

Comment: Or use `findOne()` as `var password = db.collection('users').findOne({name:"john"},{password:true, _id:false}).password`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the array returned. You access properties the same way you always do in JavaScript:

```
var password = result[0].password;
```

If you use [findOne](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) instead of [find](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/) you will just get the object directly, without the array, so then you can just use:

```
var password = result.password;
```

Side note: You should never store passwords in a way where someone (including yourself) could look inside the database and figure out a password. That means no plaintext and no encrypted passwords. They should be hashed with a random salt, and not by a fast hashing algorithm. Use [pbkdf2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) or [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Comment: Ops, sorry, It didn't worked.
I tested it on bash and worked but for some reason in Node.js version it just prints "undefined"

Comment: @ÉzhorMalkávar Which version, using `find` or `findOne`? If you're using `findOne` then it indicates that there were no results. Are you sure you still have a user named "john"?

Comment: MongoDB Shell version 2.4.9. I use findOne: `var pass = db.collection('users').findOne({name:"john"},{password:true, _id:false}).password;`And yes, I'm sure there is an user named like that, Shell finds the value using the same query (replacing `db.collection('users')` for `db.users` )